# Basic Node.js app on Heroku - free way to send emails?

Tags: php, node.js, email, heroku

I am making a basic web app on Heroku and want to be able to send basic emails. I am coming from PHP but trying to write this one in node.js. I am used to PHPMailer. I have a gmail account that I want to send a certain email from every time a certain page is accessed.  Nodemailer and postmark all seem to have costs associated - is there a 100% free option that I could use to send from Gmail? Else I may just do this in PHP.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a **POST** endpoint to your Node router to submit the data to be used to create a message and use a  library with support for SMTP with TLS/SSL security like emailjs to send standard SMTP emails via accounts like Gmail (you will need to enable third party apps in the security settings for the Gmail account). There is likely more than one library option but I am recommending one that I've used for a few years myself:

[emailjs Lib for Node](https://github.com/eleith/emailjs)

Answer (score 1):

https://www.mailgun.com/ is a service similar to postmark. They provide a simple REST API to send email and their free plan allow you to send 10,000 emails per month. Depending on the volume you want to send, this can be a viable solution for you.